# How can I add an instruction after an object creation in Django CreateView?

Tags: python, django, create-view

On my generic class based CreateView, I would like to perform an instruction which creates new objects from another model related to the current created object.

> Example: `Collection` is a model which is related to 3 differents `Element` objects. When I create a `MyCollection` object, which is related to a `Collection` and a `User`, 3 `MyElement` object must be created too and related to the newly created `MyCollection` object. One for each `Element` related to `Collection`.

```py
# models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Collection(models.Model):
    # attributes and methods...


class Element(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, # more arguments...)
    # more attributes and methods


class MyCollection(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, # more arguments...)
    collection = = models.ForeignKey(Collection, # more arguments...)
    # more attributes and methods

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        reverse(# some url with the object pk)


class MyElement(models.Model):
    element = models.ForeignKey(Element, # more arguments...)
    my_collection = models.ForeignKey(MyCollection, # more arguments...)
    # more attributes and methods
```

I'm using the generic CreateView from Django and after a little bit of research, I saw that it was possible to perform additional actions in the CreateView by overriding the get_success_url() method.

> In my example, I did something similar:

```py
# views.py

from django.views.generic import CreateView

from .utils import create_myelements_for_mycollection


class MyCollectionCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyCollection
    # more attributes and methods...

    def get_success_url(self):
        create_myelements_for_mycollection(self.get_object())  # Here is where the bug occurs, works fine without this line

        return super().get_success_url()
```

```py
# utils.py

from .models import Collection, Element, MyCollection, MyElement


def create_myelements_for_mycollection(my_collection):
    for element in my_collection.collection.elements_set.all():
        MyElement.objects.create(
            element=element,
            my_collection=my_collection,
        )
```

```py
# urls.py

from django.urls import re_path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    re_path(
        r"^myelement/l/$",
        views.MyElementListView.as_view(),
    ),
    re_path(
        r"^myelement/r/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$",
        views.MyElementDetailView.as_view(),
    ),
    re_path(
        r"^myelement/c/(?P<element_pk>\d+)/$",
        views.MyElementCreateView.as_view(),
    ),

    re_path(
        r"^mycollection/l/$",
        views.MyCollectionListView.as_view(),
    ),
    re_path(
        r"^mycollection/r/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$",
        views.MyCollectionDetailView.as_view(),
    ),
    re_path(
        r"^mycollection/c/(?P<collection_pk>\d+)/$",
        views.MyCollectionCreateView.as_view(),
    ),
]
```

When I create a new `MyCollection` object, all the `MyElements` are successfully created in the database but I got this error:

> AttributeError: Generic detail view MyCollectionCreateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

I don't understand why.

My CreateView url doesn't have any pk because when you create a new object, it doesn't have a pk yet. Also, `MyCollection` has it's own `get_absolute_url`. Without that specific instruction, I works fine.

Can someone explain me what causes the error and if there is a better way to perform an instruction like this after the object creation ?

Thank you for your help.

```
FYI:

Django 3.1
Pyhton 3.8
```

**EDIT**

I tried to use a post_save signal instead  (which is actually way cleaner to write), but I'm stuck with exactly the same error.

```py
# models.py

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .utils import create_myelements_for_mycollection


# ...models

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyCollection)
def create_myelements_for_mycollection(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    if instance is created:  # ? (Didn't look at how to write this condition in a signal yet)
        create_myelements_for_mycollection(my_collection)
```

> AttributeError: Generic detail view MyCollectionCreateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

**EDIT 2**

By removing the `get_absolute_url()` override from the `MyCollectionCreateView` class, it actually works. It's great but I would still like to know what the issue was. Probably something stupid I didn't see, if this solved the issue.

```py
# models.py

# ... previous code

class MyCollectionCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyCollection
    # more attributes and methods...

    # Removing this solved the issue
    # def get_success_url(self):
    #     create_myelements_for_mycollection(self.get_object())
    #
    #     return super().get_success_url()

# more code ...
```

Comment: can you add the URL.py?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Sure. There you go.

Comment: Oh, by removing the get_absolute_url() override from the MyCollectionCreateView class, it actually works. It's great but I would still like to know what the issue was.

Probably something stupid I didn't see, if this solved the issue.

Comment: hey @Bravo2bad did my answer help?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 Sorry for the late response. I actually didn't understand your explanation at first but after some search and some test on my project, I got it. Thank you very much. I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_absolute_url()` is used when a new instance is made for a model, as django must know where to go when a new post is created or a new instance is created.

From the error

> AttributeError: Generic detail view MyCollectionCreateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

It tells you that it must be called with an `object pk` or a `slug`, as such your construction of the URL is where the problem lies. I am not sure if the method `create_myelements_for_mycollection()` caters that need.

Ideally what you need is something like, e.g.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return f"/mycollection/{self.slug}/"
```

to generate the `URL` in the above pattern to be used for example in an anchor tag.